# fontSize in Treemap react apexchart not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, treemap, apexcharts

I'm using react apexcharts to render a treemap
I'm using fontSize inside dataLabels to set fontSize but it isn't working.

```
dataLabels: {
            //enabled: true,
            style: {
              fontSize: "20px",
            },
```

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dKWw.jpg)
Also I have used -

```
return `${textList[0]} 
                  ${textList[1]}
                  ${textList[2]}`
```

-to return string in multiple lines but that also doesn't seem to be working.
Below is the full code

```
import  React from 'react';
//import ReactApexChart from 'react-apexcharts';
import { ApexOptions } from "apexcharts";
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { getTenantDetails } from "utils/assetOverview";
const ReactApexChart = dynamic(() => import('react-apexcharts'), { ssr: false });
type datapointType={
value: number
seriesIndex: number
dataPointIndex: number
}

type tenantType={
  x:string,
  y:number
}


const TreeMap : React.FC<{areaChecked:boolean,assetCode:string}> = ({areaChecked,assetCode}) => {

let {tenantList} = getTenantDetails(assetCode);
let tenants = [] as  tenantType[]
tenants = tenantList && tenantList.map((tenant)=>{
if(areaChecked){
  return {
    "x":`${tenant.name}\n${tenant.area}ft (${tenant.percentage}%)\n${tenant.years}`,
    "y":tenant.area
  }
}else{
  return {
    "x":`${tenant.name}\n$${tenant.revenue} (${tenant.percentage}%)\n${tenant.years}`,
    "y":tenant.revenue
  }
}

})

      const series =[
        {
          data:tenants
        }
      ]
            const options:ApexOptions =  {
              legend: {
                show: false
              },
              colors:['#002776'],
              chart: {
                height: 260,
                toolbar:{
                  show:false
                }
              },
              plotOptions: {
                treemap: {
                  enableShades: false
                }
              },
              dataLabels: {
                //enabled: true,
                style: {
                  fontSize: "20px",
                },
                formatter: function(text:string,o:datapointType){
                  let textList = text.split("\n");
                  return `${textList[0]} 
                  ${textList[1]}
                  ${textList[2]}`
                }
              }
            }

          return (
            <React.Fragment>
             
            <ReactApexChart options={options} series={series} type="treemap" height={260} />
              
            </React.Fragment>
            );
}
 
export default TreeMap;
```

Also tried to set fontSize in global.scss file but the text in each rectangle overflows- [Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atBfL.jpg)

```
.apexcharts-data-labels > text {
font-size: 10px !important;
```

}

SO tried to add

```
.apexcharts-data-labels > text {

overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
```

}
but the above code doesn't seem to work